# C# Custom treeview control added to datagridview does not show at front

Tags: c#, datagridview, treeview, windows-forms-designer, datagridviewcolumn

Custom treeview control added to datagridview does not show at front.
Tried treeView1.BringToFront(); but same result.

[image]

```
        private void dataGridViewProblem_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (treeView1 != null)
            {
                treeView1.Visible = false;
            }

            if (e.RowIndex != -1 && e.ColumnIndex == dataGridViewProblem.Columns["Category"].Index)
            {
                dataGridViewProblem.Controls.Add(treeView1);

                // It returns the retangular area that represents the Display area for a cell  
                Rectangle oRectangle = dataGridViewProblem.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true);

                //Setting area for DateTimePicker Control  
                treeView1.Size = new Size(oRectangle.Width, treeView1.Height);

                // Setting Location
                treeView1.Location = new Point(oRectangle.X, oRectangle.Y + oRectangle.Height);

                treeView1.BringToFront();
                treeView1.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: It seems odd to add the tree view in this manner. However, since the code is adding the tree view to the grid itself…  `dataGridViewProblem.Controls.Add(treeView1);` then the tree view will be bounded by the size of the grid. If you don’t add the tree view to the grid by commenting out the line and move it over to the right about 10 pixels, is should display then.

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish?  At a quick glance, it looks like you may want [DataGridViewComboBoxColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn?view=netcore-3.1) instead.